# How do I convert drum loops purchased online into MIDI drum racks in my DAW?

Tags: midi, ableton-live, production, midi-controller-drums

I am totally new to the world of loops, which seem to be a pretty big deal for some genres, such as EDM and techno. I've always taken pride in creating my drum beats from scratch and modifying the sounds of each percussive element until I was satisfied.

However, i've come to realize that my grooves aren't very developed and lack "feel."

So, i've subscribed to [loopmasters.com](https://www.loopmasters.com) and found some *really* cool drum beats that can be exported as .wav files.

After importing the audio file into Ableton, however, I realized that I would not be able to edit the drum loop at all, making it pretty unusable for my purposes--I need to have far more control over the beat than that.

So, I "convert audio to MIDI," which Ableton makes super easy, but then my issue is that the notes are no longer assigned to the original kit but to whatever kit I choose from my files.  So then I sort of have the groove captured, but it sounds terrible.  Part of the benefit of loopmasters.com (I am hoping) is the ability to work with the drums the way they were produced (complete with reverb/distortion/EQ/etc.)

Is this, as far as you know, even an option with loopmasters?  Or, alternatively, do I need to choose *either* "one-shots" or "loops"?  My goal is to use the MIDI-programmed loopmaster drum loops (remember, these are purchased as audio files) as the foundation to demos and songs, modifying the original beat as I go along.

Thank you!

Update:  [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuR7X.jpg) is all I see in terms of export options.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not possible. And AFAIK there are no sites that offer that kind of source files. Loopmasters (and the alternatives) are aimed at bedroom producers who are not interested in creating their own sounds but just want to get quick results, or content creators who want to add a soundtrack very easily to their video.
To be fair (towards those sites) I think that market is a LOT bigger than the market for producers who are looking for source files to expand on and create their own beats and loops.

But it's not just market goals, it's also practicality: the loop creators will use a TON of virtual instruments, plugins and tricks to create those sounds. As you found out such a midi file is basically useless if it's not accompanied with the specific samples. So what you are asking for is that they would sell the DAW source file, with the samples and/or VST's as a separate package included. That's just not going to happen, that could literally cost thousands per loop. And technically, and rights-wise, it would be quite a (costly) challenge too.

Comment: Thank you for the response--very insightful.  However, the second link in ryan stark's answer seems to prove that it can be done?

Comment: @286642 well yeah sure, nothing prohibits anyone from creating a video and linking to some presets and free vst's. I guess a viable business model could be to create some VST libs and then have subscription based loops that you can create with those VST's. But I haven't seen such a service yet. Or did I miss something in that link?

Comment: What I took from the video was the fact that the producer was able to use one of Ableton’s built-in features, “slice to MIDI,” to unglue the separate percussive elements from each other.  This allows him to essentially reconstruct the original drum rack, which is exactly the procedure I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might find these tutorial videos useful:

[Future Music Magazine - How to process a sampled breakbeat for maximum impact](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vJaVR8t1jQ&list=PL3BS6tEyZOSyKixzYX3xZjupCkXe_kkqd&index=74)

[STRANJAH - THIS SECRET will allow you to make ANY BREAK!! | Insane Ableton Tutorial 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ja5HHcqlQr4&list=PL3BS6tEyZOSyKixzYX3xZjupCkXe_kkqd&index=62&t=710s)

[Fanu - D&B breakbeat basics #1 in Ableton Live](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPYg59BRgI0&list=PL3BS6tEyZOSzl3bQAT2VZl2boZsJey-WI&index=8&t=311s)

[Becky Saif Music - How To Process Drum Breaks | All You NEED To Know | Ableton Live 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3J4YMLmMUw&list=PL3BS6tEyZOSzl3bQAT2VZl2boZsJey-WI&index=6&t=684s)

Answer (score 0):

If you get MIDI track, then you need to provide a (most likely virtual) instrument to play back these loops.

When you click at "formats" on the site you will find a long list of choices. If you select a format, the bottom of the page will show a description. Then if you hover each position you will find what kind of data is included. In many cases it seems to be both loop and the samples it uses.

I never used this site, but I presume it would allow you to download a loop in given format, open it in dedicated software and edit as you like while preserving the original sound (at least to some degree, depending on particular format).

Note, that in most cases this will require you to have the necessary proprietary software.

Comment: I'm seeing the format drop-down menu you mention, though that just seems like a way of filtering the searches (rather than a preference for exporting).  After looking through some of the results from "loopcloud drum," which is also in format drop-down window, it looks like you can buy a "pack."  Perhaps this is what i'm looking for, though it doesn't help me with the reproducing the cool drum beats i've already spent so much time finding!

Comment: @286642 Yes, it seems to me that various loops on that site are offered only in specific formats – which is not that surprising, typically there is no straightforward or automatic way to transfer sounds between different virtual instruments.